# Can I add, newly created Tag to an existing questions by suggest an edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

Recently I am looking for an answer regarding angularjs [ngIdle](http://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/).

I see few questions are existing about the `ngIdle`, but there is no tag for it.

If some one is creating the `ngIdle` tag (since I don't have enough reputation to create the tag), can I add the newly created tag to the [`ng-idle`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22ng-idle%22), [`ngIdle`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22ngIdle%22) existing questions by suggest an edit.

Is this accepted in stackoverflow or we should not? Suggestions please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable. It is nice of you to ask if you're not sure about creating the tag though, so you can get input from the community about whether or not it would be a good on-topic tag for Stack Overflow.  It looks ok to me in this case, so I went ahead and added the [ng-idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-idle) tag to one of the questions in the search results you linked to. You can suggest edits to any others that should have the tag. (Please make sure you fix anything else that needs fixing when you suggest tag edits.)

Comment: Thanks for adding the `ng-idle` tag. I will keep in mind about your note _Please make sure you fix anything else that needs fixing_

Comment: It is also a good idea to have a descriptive comment about why you are making the edit or why it is important.

Answer (score -1):

Please **only** do this for questions that are worth it, e.g.

- The question is new, so adding the tag makes it more likely it will get answered.
- The question or its answers have up votes, so having the question listed on the tag page is of value.

Remember that approving edits take time and effort, so don’t just add a tag to 101 low quality questions.

Try to make other improvements to the question as well, but if a question is 6 months only, has only had 20 views  and has no up voted answers – it may be best just to leave it.   The system will auto deleted it anyway if no one shows any interest in it.

(Most "mass" retagging is best done by users with enough rep to bepass the aproval system.  Even then only after getting agreement on meta)