# Can I ask a question that not related to any problem just to create a tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

To create a tag you need at least 1500 reputation points and need to ask or edit a question and add the new tag to your question, this is clear.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Like **JoseK** said in the post *[How to add a new tag on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103676/how-to-add-a-new-tag-on-stack-overflow)*:

> You need 1500 reputation on Stack Overflow to create a new tag.
>   Unfortunately, you don't have that much yet.
>
> If you did have 1500 rep, then you could create a new tag simply by
>   adding the tag to a question. The tag will be created automatically.

Now I want to create a tag, so I want to ask a question that is not related to any problem. Is that possible or is this not a bad idea?

Or is there another way to create a tag without using this way?

Any clarification about this answer here also?

[When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-our-site?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Like what they say here:

> **If you have enough reputation to create the tag, and if you think
>   there is a clear need for a tag, go ahead and create it yourself**. If
>   the new tag causes controversy, you can always come back to your
>   site's meta to ask the community to judge it.

So is there another way to create a tag?

Comment: If you have no question, then there's no need for the tag, no?

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287133/can-i-ask-a-question-not-related-to-any-problem-just-to-create-a-tag). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: @user000001 why you edit my question

Comment: i want to delete it so there are no other way, i flag it to the moderators

Comment: Improve the question. Do not deface it.

Comment: mmm good idea, i will change the question then thank you @EdCottrell, but i really want to delete it can you help me please?

Comment: We prefer not to delete questions that folks have taken the time to contribute answers to. If the question can be improved, please edit it to do so. To be clear: that means write the question in a better way. It doesn't mean change it to something else entirely.

Comment: the source of the idea is bad not the question, so i improve the question or let it like this, nothing will changes @EdCottrell and until you, you down vote it i'm wrong, so the question is not good at all !

Comment: @YoucefLaidani So then leave it alone. If you can't make it better, it's just not a good question. Don't worry about it. Downvotes on Meta aren't the same as on Main, so it's not hurting you.

Comment: mmm, so this is your answer, the answer from a moderator i think should be better, and helpful, any way thank you @EdCottrell

Answer (score 24):

If you don't already have a question about a practical programming problem, then there is no clear need (as stated in the quote) for that tag right now. The tag can be created when the need arises. Please do not post a placeholder question just to create a tag.

Comment: i want to create to use it with others, not for me you get it?

Comment: I didn't get it because you never said anything about creating a tag for others to use. If someone wants to ask a question, they can just ask, and you or someone else can add the tag after the fact.

Comment: @YoucefLaidani why have you asked this here **and** on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287133/can-i-ask-a-question-not-related-to-any-problem-just-to-create-a-tag#287134)?

Comment: mmm i really maked a mistake, i don't know where should i ask this type of question this is why @JonClements?

Comment: @JonClements how i can delete my question, i can't now because it already have an answer

Answer (score 6):

Creating a question just to create a tag is the tail wagging the dog - putting the cart in front of the horse.

Tags exist because questions exist, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

This wouldn't even work.  Since your question isn't an appropriate question, it'd just get closed and deleted very quickly, and the tag would then end up being deleted for not having any questions associated with it.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to ask a new question to create a tag. [You can do tag edits to existing questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295497/4356188) Don't ask useless questions just for the sake of making a new tag.

Comment: Don't make useless edits just for the sake of making a new tag.

Comment: @Makoto The OP was asking if there was a way to add a tag for other people, other than asking a new question themselves. The answer here is valid, because (if you assume innocence) - the OP was simply trying to help others make their questions clearer by creating a tag for them, and this proposes a valid solution, as not to create a useless question.